# Non-continuous line numbering with Sweave and listings

Tags: r, latex, sweave, listings

I'm writing a report in LaTeX, embedding several R scripts, which are reported in non-contiguous Sweave chunks.

I found some pretty useful comments on Stackoverflow on how to customize **Sweave** and the **listings** package to highlight code and numbering lines.
I modified the original **sweave.sty** package as follows, to take advantage of **listings** while avoiding to burden my LaTeX documents with too many settings.

Basically, I'm having trouble with the line numbering options. As configured, (firstnumber=last), the lines are numbered progressively across the document.
If I set firstnumber=auto , the numbering restarts from 1 at each chunk of R code.

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx,ae,fancyvrb}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\RequirePackage{upquote}}{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl, fontsize=\small}

\newenvironment{Schunk}{}{}

\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\indexfonction}[1]{\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\definecolor{gris90}{gray}{0.95}

\lstdefinelanguage{Renhanced}[]{R}{%
   sensitive,%
   morecomment=[l]\#,%
   morestring=[d][\color{RoyalPurple}]",%
   morestring=[d][\color{RoyalPurple}]',
  alsoletter={.\%_},
  alsoother={:_\$}}

\lstset{language=Renhanced,extendedchars=false,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, 
  columns=flexible,
  commentstyle=\textsl,
  numbers=left, 
  numberstyle=\small \ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\mdseries,
  showstringspaces=false,
  index=[1][keywords], 
  indexstyle=\indexfonction}


\lstnewenvironment{Sinput}[1][]{
 \lstset{%
   language={Renhanced},
   basicstyle=\small \ttfamily,
   columns=flexible,  
   frame=single,                             
   backgroundcolor=\color{gris90},           
   numbers=left, 
   numberstyle=\small \ttfamily,
   firstnumber=last,
   #1
 }
}{}
\lstnewenvironment{Soutput}[1][]{
 \lstset{%
   language={Renhanced},
   basicstyle=\small \ttfamily, 
   columns=flexible,
   numbers=right, 
   numberstyle=\tiny,
   firstnumber=last,
   #1
 }
}{}
```

I would like to find an intermediate solution, where the numbering progresses across different chunks of the same script, but restarts form 1 at the beginning of a different script (possibly by specifying it manually).

The trouble is, I think, that I cannot specify manually the name of the listings, because Sweave does it in the background.

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a pseudo-solution.

Before beginning a chunk of code opening a new script, type the following lines of code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=1] 
\end{lstlisting}
```

This won't produce any visible output in the document and will reset the line numbering of the following chunk to 1 (or any other desired number).

Needless to say, any more elegant solutions are still welcome!